# Django project working on IP address of droplet. But, it does not work on custom domain

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, web-deployment, gunicorn

I have my domain on GoDaddy and my hosting setup in DigitalOcean. So after I setup my basic django project, I used a droplet to deploy the code to an IP address. When I run this command, my project was running at my [IP_ADDRESS]:8000:

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /home/USER_NAME/projectdir/test_project test_project.wsgi
```

Then, I put the three digital ocean nameservers in GoDaddy. I also modified the settings.py file by using the ALLOWED_HOSTS variables:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP_ADDRESS', 'www.DOMAIN_NAME', 'DOMAIN_NAME']
```

My Nginx configuration looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    listen 80;
    server_name IP_ADDRESS DOMAIN_NAME www.DOMAIN_NAME;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/USER_NAME/projectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

But still, I get 'This Site can't be reached'. I also checked that the nameservers have been updated by using https://lookup.icann.org/en. So I don't know where the problem lies. If you need any additional information let me know. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you want nginx to run on ports 80 and 8000? I think your main application won't start because port 8000 is already in use, and this should be the problem. Try removing `listen 8000;` or change it to different number if possible, and restart your service

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Even after removing that line, I get the same This site can't be reached message. Do you need some other information that can help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Just a quick question, where is the root parameter supposed to point to? Will it be pointing to the same directory as the manage.py file or where?